# Loop through nested JSON with php

Tags: php, json, nested

I have a json file with the following structure:

```
[{
    "Item": {
        "name": "Item 1",
        "schedule": {
            "class": "Class",
            "uic": "UIC"
        },
        "days": "Mondays",
        "segment": {
            "branding": "A1",
            "location": [{
                "location_type": "L1",
                "time": "18:00"
            }, {
                "location_type": "L2",
                "time": "18:15"
            }, {
                "location_type": "L3",
                "time": "18:18"
            }]
        },
        "transaction": "Trans"
}
}, {        "Item": {
        "name": "Item 2",
        "schedule": {
            "class": "Class",
            "uic": "UIC"
        },
        "days": "Tuesdays",
        "segment": {
            "branding": "A2",
            "location": [{
                "location_type": "Lu1",
                "time": "19:00"
            }, {
                "location_type": "L2",
                "time": "19:15"
            }, {
                "location_type": "L3",
                "time": "19:18"
            }, {
                "location_type": "L4",
                "time": "19:25"
            }]
        },
        "transaction": "Trans"
    }
}]
```

I am using php's json decode to out put this data, but I'm not sure how to achieve what I want. I am trying to out put this data as a new line for every location_type value for each item, basically listing out every combination for each item.

The example below is essentially what I am looking to output:

```
Item 1, Class, UIC, Mondays, A1, L1, 18:00, Trans
Item 1, Class, UIC, Mondays, A1, L2, 18:15, Trans
Item 1, Class, UIC, Mondays, A1, L3, 18:17, Trans
Item 2, Class, UIC, Tuesdays, A2, L1, 19:00, Trans
Item 2, Class, UIC, Tuesdays, A2, L2, 19:15, Trans
Item 2, Class, UIC, Tuesdays, A2, L3, 19:17, Trans
Item 2, Class, UIC, Tuesdays, A2, L4, 19:25, Trans
```

I'm assuming I need to drill down to the location and then loop through it for each item, but my php is limited and I can't find anything that seems to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: I can be wrong, but your JSON seems incorrect.
It's an array with one big object inside. Which has two properties, and each of them has name "Item". Which is incorrect.

Comment: @OlegDubas You're absolutely right, I have corrected the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JSON would be correct (and it is not), the code would be like:

```
foreach($JSON as $item)
{
    $item = $item->Item; // because you changed the code

    for($i=0;$i<count($item->segment->location);$i++)
    {
        echo $item->name, ', ';
        echo $item->schedule->class. ', ';
        echo $item->schedule->uic. ', ';
        echo $item->days. ', ';
        echo $item->segment->branding. ', ';
        echo $item->segment->location[$i]->location_type. ', ';
        echo $item->segment->location[$i]->time. ', ';
        echo $item->segment->transaction. '<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assume your json are on variable $json

```
$array = json_decode($json);

foreach ($array as $value) {
    foreach ($value->Item->segment->location as $loc) {
        echo sprintf('%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s <br>', 
            $value->Item->name,
            $value->Item->schedule->class,
            $value->Item->schedule->uic,
            $value->Item->days,
            $value->Item->segment->branding,
            $loc->location_type,
            $loc->time,
            $value->Item->transaction
        );
    }
}
```

this will output

```
Item 1, Class, UIC, Mondays, A1, L1, 18:00, Trans 
Item 1, Class, UIC, Mondays, A1, L2, 18:15, Trans 
Item 1, Class, UIC, Mondays, A1, L3, 18:18, Trans 
Item 2, Class, UIC, Tuesdays, A2, Lu1, 19:00, Trans 
Item 2, Class, UIC, Tuesdays, A2, L2, 19:15, Trans 
Item 2, Class, UIC, Tuesdays, A2, L3, 19:18, Trans 
Item 2, Class, UIC, Tuesdays, A2, L4, 19:25, Trans
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $input = '[
        {
            "Item": {
                "name": "Item 1",
                "schedule": {
                    "class": "Class",
                    "uic": "UIC"
                },
                "days": "Mondays",
                "segment": {
                    "branding": "A1",
                    "location": [
                        {
                            "location_type": "L1",
                            "time": "18:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "location_type": "L2",
                            "time": "18:15"
                        },
                        {
                            "location_type": "L3",
                            "time": "18:18"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "transaction": "Trans"
            }
        },
        {
            "Item": {
                "name": "Item 2",
                "schedule": {
                    "class": "Class",
                    "uic": "UIC"
                },
                "days": "Tuesdays",
                "segment": {
                    "branding": "A2",
                    "location": [
                        {
                            "location_type": "Lu1",
                            "time": "19:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "location_type": "L2",
                            "time": "19:15"
                        },
                        {
                            "location_type": "L3",
                            "time": "19:18"
                        },
                        {
                            "location_type": "L4",
                            "time": "19:25"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "transaction": "Trans"
            }
        }
    ]';

    $items = json_decode($input);

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $item = $item->Item;
        for ($i = 0, $l = count($item->segment->location); $i < $l; $i++ ) {
            echo $item->name . ", ";
            echo $item->schedule->class . ", ";
            echo $item->schedule->uic . ", ";
            echo $item->days . ", ";
            echo $item->segment->branding . ", ";
            echo $item->segment->location[$i]->location_type . ", ";
            echo $item->segment->location[$i]->time . ", ";
            echo $item->transaction;
            echo "<br/>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $jsonStr = <<<JSON
[{
    "Item": {
        "name": "Item 1",
        "schedule": {
            "class": "Class",
            "uic": "UIC"
        },
        "days": "Mondays",
        "segment": {
            "branding": "A1",
            "location": [{
                "location_type": "L1",
                "time": "18:00"
            }, {
                "location_type": "L2",
                "time": "18:15"
            }, {
                "location_type": "L3",
                "time": "18:18"
            }]
        },
        "transaction": "Trans"
}
}, {        "Item": {
        "name": "Item 2",
        "schedule": {
            "class": "Class",
            "uic": "UIC"
        },
        "days": "Tuesdays",
        "segment": {
            "branding": "A2",
            "location": [{
                "location_type": "Lu1",
                "time": "19:00"
            }, {
                "location_type": "L2",
                "time": "19:15"
            }, {
                "location_type": "L3",
                "time": "19:18"
            }, {
                "location_type": "L4",
                "time": "19:25"
            }]
        },
        "transaction": "Trans"
    }
}]
JSON;

$arr = json_decode($jsonStr);


foreach($arr as $item)
{

    $locations = $item->Item->segment->location;
    foreach($locations as $loc)
    {
        echo $item->Item->name, ', ';
        echo $item->Item->schedule->class. ', ';
        echo $item->Item->schedule->uic. ', ';
        echo $item->Item->days. ', ';
        echo $item->Item->segment->branding. ', ';
        echo $loc->location_type. ', ';
        echo $loc->time. ', ';
        echo $item->Item->transaction. '<br>';
    }
}
```